# Store locator - Directions from postcode to chosen store

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a JavaScript postcode search that searches for the 3 closet stores in the UK depending on what is entered into the input. At the moment it finds the 3 stores fine.

Firstly, I want to drop a marker at the postcode entered in the input.

Secondly, when the three results show up, they are marked on the map. I want to have a link called *directions* that, once clicked, will show directions from the start to the chosen store.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work...however it does get the postcode data from the input and from the directions link and shows them in the console. Will I need to convert them into long and lat for it to work?

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('get-directions').name;
    //console.log(start, end)
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

I have this code for my start marker, but this doesn't seem to work either

```
function initialize() {
    var start_marker = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('address').value);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: start_marker
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,
          draggable:false,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: start_marker,
        });
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }
```

This part gets the long/lat data from the postcode,

```
this.geocode = function(address, callbackFunction) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var result = {};
      result.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      result.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      callbackFunction(result);
      //console.log(result);
        //console.log("Geocoding " + geometry.location + " OK");
        addMarker(map, results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      callbackFunction(null);
    }
  });
```

And the function for the addMarker is here:

```
function addMarker(map, location) {

console.log("Setting marker for (location: " + location + ")");
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map : map,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
position : location
});
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor for a [google.maps.LatLng requires two floating point numbers as arguments](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), not a string:

```
var start_marker = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('address').value);
```

If all you have is an address, you need to use the [Geocoding service to retrieve coordinates for that address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) if you want to display a marker on the map.

Comment: Ah great thank you. But for some reason the marker will not add. I have the geolocation data but it doesn;t add to the map at all. Is this code correct?
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map : map,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   position : location
  });

Comment: Whether that code is correct or not depends on what "location" is.  Two things: 1. posted code in the comments is difficult to read, you should edit your question to include it and format it in a reasonable way.  2.  The Geocoder is asynchronous, if "location" comes from the Geocoder are you using it in the callback function?

Comment: Yes location comes from the Geocoder, and yes I am using it in the callbackfunction. When I console.log(location) it shows 54.9861334, -1.5379448999999568 which is the correct long/lat on the postcode I am entering into the input. Yes I will do so now